# How to convert the "time" from DateTime into int?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datagrid, converters

I have a DataGrid which contains a few values that are in hours and I wanted to know:

How to get ONLY the time from my DataGrid and convert it into an int (or double) variable.

My goal is to do a few operations with my DataGrid time values, like to add numbers into it

EXAMPLE:
Using my "dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value.ToString();" It'll show a DateTime value (which is inside my DataGrid), with this value, I wanna filter ONLY the time from this and convert it into an int

the part of my code which I wanna "capture" the time:

```
txtAtiv.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(); 
string value = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString(); 
lblLeft.Text = value.Split(' ')[1];
```

I wanna get the "value" (which is a DateTime value from the DataGrid) and convert it into an int.

note: 
- The date for me in my dataGrid it's not relevant, I only have to pick the time (and yes, I know that I can't "split" DateTime to do them separately)

Comment: How do you expect a time could be converted to an int?  E.g. how would 4:27 PM be represented as an int?

Comment: Is it a `string` or a `DateTime`?  If a `DateTime` you can use `DateTime.TimeOfDay` to get the time as a `TimeSpan` and from that you can get the time in seconds, minutes, or hours.  Otherwise I would just parse to a `DateTime` first if it is a string.

Comment: Well, that's my doubt thought. I wanna know if there's a way to do it, like convert the time into a serial number

Comment: You can convert it to a double using [`DateTime.ToOADate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I'm not sure if that's what you meant. You can convert it back using [`DateTime.FromOADate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: it is a DateTime value which is on a DataGrid.
But the result is shown on a label

Comment: I tried to parse it but it only shows me this error:
"When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime Object".

Comment: @MattDAVM Can you show us that code?  Also why are you parsing it if it's already a `DateTime`?

Comment: Thank you Matthew! I'll try this one.
But would DateTime.ToOADate() only convert the DATE value?

Comment: txtAtiv.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   
    string value = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    lblLeft.Text = value.Split(' ')[1];

I wanna get the "value" (which is a DateTime from the DataGrid) and convert it into an int

Comment: @MattDAVM That will include the date AND the time, but re-reading your post, it seems that you only want the time part.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I only want the time part to turn into an int (if the date convert it as well it won't be relevant to my program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to convert string to DateTime. Use DateTime.TryParse(string value, out DateTime dt).  Then as Mathew Watson rightly suggested,  get the value of variable dt converted to milliseconds using dt.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds. It is also possible to convert the span in TotalSeconds or TotalMinutes if it suits your requirement.
Try to avoid calling ToString() method directly before checking if cell value is null. If I want to avoid the check, I would make compiler to do it by using something like : Rows[3].Cells[2].Value + "" instead of Value.ToString().

Comment: Yes dt would be variable.

Comment: Right here at the beginning it shows the error on
"DateTime.TryParse(string value, out DateTime dt)"
the error:
'System.DateTime' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: I'd specify dt as a variable of which kind?

Answer (score 6):

If you are willing to be limited to millisecond resolution, then this is fairly easy.

Given a date/time that you want to get the time part from as an int, you can get the number of milliseconds since midnight, like so:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
int timeMsSinceMidnight = (int)dateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
```

If you want to reconstitute the original date and time from this, you need the original date and the time since midnight in milliseconds:

```
DateTime date = dateTime.Date; // Midnight.
DateTime restoredTime = date.AddMilliseconds(timeMsSinceMidnight);
```

Test program:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine("Original date/time: " + dateTime );

int timeMsSinceMidnight = (int)dateTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;

DateTime date = dateTime.Date; // Midnight.
DateTime restoredTime = date.AddMilliseconds(timeMsSinceMidnight);

Console.WriteLine("Restored date/time: " + restoredTime);
```

The value returned from `time.TimeOfDay` is of type `TimeSpan`, which is convenient for storing time-of-day values.

If you want to turn your "milliseconds since midnight" back into a `TimeSpan`, you just do this:

```
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeMsSinceMidnight);
```

Comment: I'll test it right now and show the result right here

Answer (score 1):

Mixing Mathew's and Mukesh Adhvaryu's answers, I got into this one, and it fits perfectly on what I need, thank you guys for your support!

```
 txtAtiv.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value + "";

        string value = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value + "";
        lblLeft.Text = value.Split(' ')[1];
        textStatus.Text = "";



        DateTime timeConvert;
        DateTime.TryParse(value, out timeConvert);

        double time;
        time = timeConvert.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;


        var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time);


        lblSoma.Text = timeSpan.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        string time1 = "11:15 AM";
        string time2 = "11:15 PM";
        var t1 = ConvertTimeToInt(time1);
        var t2 = ConvertTimeToInt(time2);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", t1);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", t2);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}", ConvertIntToTime(t1));
        Console.WriteLine("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}", ConvertIntToTime(t2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static long ConvertTimeToInt(string input)
    {
        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        TimeSpan span = date.TimeOfDay;
        Console.WriteLine("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}", date);
        return span.Ticks;
    }

    static DateTime ConvertIntToTime(long input)
    {
        TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromTicks(input);
        var date = new DateTime(span.Ticks);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}", date);
        return date;
    }
```