# How to create an advanced countdown timer

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, timer, countdown

Well, this question is related to this one, so you guys can understand it better

- [How to convert the "time" from DateTime into int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36913659/)

My Answer to it:

```
txtAtiv.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value + "";

string value = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value + "";
lblLeft.Text = value.Split(' ')[1];
textStatus.Text = "";

DateTime timeConvert;
DateTime.TryParse(value, out timeConvert);

double time;
time = timeConvert.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;

var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time);

lblSoma.Text = timeSpan.ToString();
timer2.Start();
```

According to the answer I wrote right there, I want to know if there's a way I can apply it to a timer and do the DataGrid values (converted) turn into a timer value. So if I press a button they start the countdown.

I have tried to insert this code inside the timer:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string timeOp = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value + "";
    DateTime timeConvert;
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime.TryParse(timeOp, out timeConvert);

    double time;
    time = timeConvert.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
    var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time);

    if (time > 0)
    {
        time = time - 1000; //(millisec)
        lblCountdown.text = time.ToString();
    }
}
```

didn't count down or anything, does someone has an idea of what should I do or why it isn't working?

Comment: Can you show the code where you started the Timer?

Comment: It happens when I press the button. forgot to put this on it, but still, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you still show it?  You should be able to still edit your question.

Comment: timer2_Tick or you mean some timer2_Start?

Comment: @BobC I think it's this `timer2_Start()` that you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `time` never changes, because you create it again fresh each time.

To solve this, you have to declare the variable you decrement outside of the `Tick` event.

Put these two variables on your form:

```
private int milliSecondsLeft = 0;
private bool timeSet = false;
```

Then change the 'tick' event to this:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!timeSet) // only get the value once
    {
        string dateTimeFromGrid = "4/29/2016 5:00:00 AM"; //hardcoded for simplicity, get the string from your grid
        DateTime fromGrid;
        DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeFromGrid, out fromGrid);
        milliSecondsLeft = (int)fromGrid.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;  
        timeSet = true;
    }

    milliSecondsLeft = milliSecondsLeft - 100; // timer's default Interval is 100 milliseconds

    if (milliSecondsLeft > 0)
    {
        var span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, milliSecondsLeft);
        lblCountdown.Text = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }
    else
    {
        timer2.Stop();
    }
}
```

Make sure

Comment: I'll check this out and give you a feedback.

Comment: Glad to hear. Please take some time to understand *why* it worked, it will save you headaches later on.