# Multiple countdown timer + button

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, button, timer

NOTE: This question is related to this one as well

- [How to create an advanced countdown timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943993/)

I have a timer which is activated by a button that starts the countdown of the supposed activity. But I have a problem, when I press the same button again, the program must use another time (specified inside a datagrid) and start the countdown again, and if I press the button again, another time and so on.

Shall I use multiple timers or is there a way I can use the same timer, but with new ("reset") values if I press the button?

(If you guys want me to show more of the code, just tell me I'll post here)

```
private bool timeSet2 = false;
int f = 1;
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DateTime timeConvert;
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

    string timeOp = dataGridView1.Rows[f].Cells[2].Value + "";
    f++;

    if (!timeSet2) // only get the value once
    {
        DateTime.TryParse(timeOp, out timeConvert);
        milliSecondsLeft = (int)timeConvert.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
        timeSet2 = true;
    }

    milliSecondsLeft = milliSecondsLeft - 1000;

    if (milliSecondsLeft > 0)
    {
        var span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, milliSecondsLeft);
        lblLeft.Text = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }
    else
    {
        timer3.Stop();
    }
```

I need to fit a button right here so if I press it, my program will start another countdown. But I don't know if I'll have to create another time for this.

Comment: What kind of timer are you using? Most (all?) timers let you change their interval. For example, the Windows Forms Timer has an [Interval property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.interval%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you can change.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'm using the most common timer, which people use it to do clock in their forms, with interval in 1000ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same timer and reset it for each countdown. But I think you are misunderstanding the the functionality of the timer. The `timer_Tick` event occurs every time the interval of the timer has elapsed. Update the `milliSecondsLeft` variable on your button click event.

**You have to move some code to the `button_Click` event.**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    milliSecondsLeft = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[f].Cells[2].Value)*1000;
    f++;
    timer3.Start();
}
```

**Your `timer_Tick` event would then look like:**

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    milliSecondsLeft = milliSecondsLeft - 1000;
    if (milliSecondsLeft > 0)
    {
        var span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, milliSecondsLeft);
        lblLeft.Text = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }
    else
    {
        timer3.Stop();
    }
}
```

**Some other things:**

- Are you sure you want to start with the second column of your `dataGridView` with `int f = 1;`
- I did not understand your time conversion so I changed it. Now it expects the countdown time in your `dataGridView` to be in seconds. But perhaps your code is right for your purpose

Comment: my conversion was kinda messy, i gotta be honest. At first, I converted an `string` value to `DateTime`value, second, I converted it to `Double`just to make the countdown of the milliseconds -1000, after that I converted it again to `DateTime`to show the information on my label.

Comment: and yes, I'm sure, because my time values are on the second column. And the f would give me the definition of the second row (my first row is already being used by another button, thats why haha)